# String replace an apostrophe for mkdir

Tags: php, string, replace, mkdir

I'm looking for some help trying to replace an apostrophe in a text string which can then be used to create a directory. So far, I have the following:

```
$fname = str_replace(' ', '_', $_POST['name']);
$fname1 = str_replace("'", "", $fname);
if (!file_exists($fname1)) {
    mkdir($fname1, 0777, true);
}
```

The problem is that when an apostrophe is used, the folder gets created with a backslash. For example, the word Test's would create the folder Test\s. I am also inserting the string into a database and this works fine (removes the apostrophe), it's just the folder creation that i'm having trouble with.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value of $_POST['name'] before you attempt to remove spaces and apostrophes?

Comment: Hi Nathan. Just tried it and it still didn't work.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion to fix this. I meant see what the output of $_POST['name'] actually is. You may find that by the time it reaches your string replace a backslash already exists.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Well when I post the string into a database, it doesn't have any backslash.

Comment: Try `$curl --data "name=c's" http://path/to/location/name/of/file.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st issue:
don´t use values of any `$_REQUEST`, as `$_GET` or `$_POST` unsanitized. See reference on  http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

2nd: `file_exists` checks for an exististing file, you better use `is_dir` to check for existing directory, and normally you should get the permission using the umask-wrap

```
    if(!is_dir($target)) {
        $oldumask= umask(0);
        mkdir($target, 0777, true);
        umask($oldumask);
    }
```

3rd: you´re on the right way, with the `str_replace` method.

As the simpliest method you could use arrays for multiple replacements.
But there are a lot of other sophisticated methods.

```
$fname = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); // or FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING or so
if ($fname && $fname != '') {
    $notwanted = array("'",'"',' ','-','+');
    $wanted = array('','','_','_','_');

    $fname = str_replace($notwanted, $wanted, $fname);
    if (!is_dir($fname)) {
        $oldumask= umask(0);
        mkdir($fname, 0777, true);
        umask($oldumask);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps for the first steps

Comment: You won’t be able to create the directory if there’s already a file with the same name. So `file_exists` is actually better here.

Comment: Ah, this is true. So using both makes sense, or?

Comment: Are you sure ? Have to try that, never dealed with this option :-)

Comment: Well, you could throw an error if the file exists but isn’t a directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, the directory is still being created with a backslash in place of the apostrophe.

Comment: I’m not sure about Windows file systems, but on Unix file systems directory entries’ names must be unique.

Comment: @mckeegan: Ah, may be I misunderstood you. You WANT the apostrophe in the name ? I thought, you want remove it.

Comment: @ddlab No, I do wantto remove it... but the string replace doesn't work when it creates the directory... When i post the value to a database, the apostrophe is gone (works perfect) but when it creates the directory, it replaces the apostrophe with a backslash (I want to remove the apostrophe).

Comment: if you want to remove the backslash, just add it to the $notwanted array

Comment: guess, that the backslash is created earlier, already before the replace method

Comment: Are you using any javascript before sending the post data ? Some form validators or so ?

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks @ddlab you've been a great help! The replacing a backslash worked but i've also implemented your other suggestions :)

Comment: I think it was because I wasn't replacing the backslash... well that solved the problem anyway but it's strange that no backslash appeared when it was posted to a database before.

Answer (score 0):

in addition:
I use this function to replace anything including international characters to get a clean url conforme string, to use with folder creations or readable site urls

```
function makeurlstring($str) {
    $from = array("![ÄÆäæ]!u", "![ÀÁÂÃÅàáâãå]!u", "![ÖöØø]!u", "![ÒÓÔÕòóôõ]!u", "![Üü]!u", "![ÙÚÛùúû]!u", "![ÈÉÊËèéêë]!u", "![ÌÍÎÏ]!u", "![Ýý]!u", "![Çç]!u", "![ÐðþÞ]!u", "![Ññ]!u", "![Šš]!u", "![Žž]!u", "!ß!u", "!&!u", "!¡!u", "!§!u", "!€!u", "!¥!u", "!£!u", "![\"\'\?\s]!u", "![^a-z0-9_-]!u");
    $to = array('ae', 'a', 'oe', 'o', 'ue', 'u', 'e', 'i', 'y', 'c', 'th', 'n', 's', 'z', 'ss', 'und', '!', 'paragraph', 'euro', 'yen', 'pound', '_', '');
    return preg_replace($from, $to, strtolower(trim($str)));
}
```

works like a charme

Comment: Better use transliteration provided by [`iconv`](http://php.net/ivonc) or [*Normalizer* class](http://php.net/class.normalizer).

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes I know that there are a lot of possibilities, but, as I am not soooo advanced, I use what I understand. iconv has a lot of issues with setlocale, with strange results, and the use of normalizer class I did not understand until now. But thanks anyway, you will be right I guess.